# Flask-WTForm FileField returns None instead of the file uploaded

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, filefield

I am trying to upload a picture using Flask-WTForm's FileField. But even though I upload a picture, it can't detect it.

The form is created as:

```
class User_settings_profile_picture_form(FlaskForm):
    picture = FileField('Update profile picture', validators=[DataRequired(), FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Update')
```

The **route** where the form is used is like:

```
profile_pic_form = User_settings_profile_picture_form()
.
.
.
if profile_pic_form.validate_on_submit():
    if profile_pic_form.picture.data:
        ...
else:
    #for debugging purposes
    print("Is valid: " + profile_pic_form.validate())
    print("Errors: " + profile_pic_form.errors)
    print("Request files: " + request.files)
```

The `print` statements are for debugging purposes and in the console it is like:

```
Is valid: False
Errors: {'picture': ['This field is required.']}
Request files: ImmutableMultiDict([])
```

The html looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ profile_pic_form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="mb-3">
        <h3>Profile Picture</h3>
        {{ profile_pic_form.picture(class="form-control-file", placeholder="Enter new Bio") }}
        {{ profile_pic_form.submit(class="mt-3 btn btn-primary mb-5") }}
    </div>
</form>
```

If I print the `profile_pic_form.picture.data`, it gives me `None`.

Does anyone know why this is happening. I looked through SO, but did not find a solution for this specific case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was in the html. It should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Instead of just:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

Edit: Read the [documentation](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/0.15.x/form/) to understand better.